# How can multiple addon domain share single Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm working on a project where I have to add multiple **addon domains** which will be sharing a common Laravel file.
I have installed Laravel on a subdomain called **'studio.udee.space'.**
And now I have three addon domains like abc.com pqr.com and xyz.com which will be pointing to the same subdomain that is 'studio.udee.sapce' so that **I don't need to install Laravel separate for each addon domain.**
I have done this for subdomains like user1.studio.udee.space, user2.studio.udee.space now I wanted to do this with addon domains

Answer (score 0):

that's archived with the configuration of your webserver: nginx, apache , whatever you use:

- with apache I recommand reading the docs to rewrite: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/
- and virtual hosts: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/
- and at least the getting started guide: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/getting-started.html
- With nginx I would read (at least) the beginners guide: https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html
- and the chapter about servernames here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

**additionally** you can try this library: https://github.com/gecche/laravel-multidomain